# Maze Game c++ 41 by 41 array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2017

Is there a fast way to make a 2d array that's 41 by 41 using char, seems I am spending more time inputting each line and is taking long then id like. Any suggestions. Here's what I have got so far.

```
char board[41][41] = {
    {'+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+'},
    {'|','@','|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|',' ',' ',' ','|',' ',' ',' ','|',' ',' ',' ','|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|',' ','|'},
    {'+',' ','+','-','+','-','+',' ','+','-','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+','-','+','-','+','-','+',' ','+',' ','+',' ','+','-','+','-','+',' ','+',' ','+'},
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                        ,' ','|'},
    {'+'                                                                                                                                                            ,'+'}
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                            ,'|'}
    {'+'                                                                                                                                                            ,'+'}
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                            ,'|'}
    {'+'                                                                                                                                                            ,'+'}
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                            ,'|'}
    {'+'                                                                                                                                                            ,'+'}
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                            ,'|'}
    {'+'                                                                                                                                                            ,'+'}
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                            ,'|'}
    {'+'                                                                                                                                                            ,'+'}
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                            ,'|'}
    {'+'                                                                                                                                                            ,'+'}
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                            ,'|'}
    {'+'                                                                                                                                                            ,'+'}
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                            ,'|'}
    {'+'                                                                                                                                                            ,'+'}
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                            ,'|'}
    {'+'                                                                                                                                                            ,'+'}
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                            ,'|'}                   
    {'+'                                                                                                                                                            ,'+'}
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                            ,'|'}
    {'+'                                                                                                                                                            ,'+'}
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                            ,'|'}
    {'+'                                                                                                                                                            ,'+'}   
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                            ,'|'}
    {'+'                                                                                                                                                            ,'+'}
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                            ,'|'}
    {'+'                                                                                                                                                            ,'+'}
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                            ,'|'} 
    {'+'                                                                                                                                                            ,'+'}
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                            ,'|'}
    {'+'                                                                                                                                                            ,'+'}
    {'|'                                                                                                                                                        ,'x','|'}   
    {'+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+','-','+'}
```

Comment: Write a program or script which auto-generates some kind of default maze for you? Then modify the generated output to fit your requirements?

Comment: You can use create the array an use a loop to initialize your values. But you need to provide specifics on what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Put it in a text file then just load text file into an array or multidimensional array (prefer using `std::array`).

Comment: I figured out my array and made a switch statement for movement but when my player meets a wall noted by + it passes through and I can't figure out why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is definitely a better way. Check out for-loops.

```
char board[40][40];
int rows = 40;
int cols = 40;

for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for(int c = 0; c< cols; c++) {
        // Whatever logic you want to use to populate location r, c in your array
    }
}
```

For further reading on maze generation algorithms, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm

Comment: what logic would I use to random populate the maze with a start and exit point with the array using + - | characters